# Why am I getting `method_missing`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure but I think my something may not be right with my relations? I'm getting `method_missing`. Is it because I'm getting an Array back from active-record.?

```
event = Event.last
  Event Load (16.2ms)  SELECT "event".* FROM "event" ORDER BY "event"."sid" DESC, "event"."cid" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Event sid: 4, cid: 49, signature: 493, timestamp: "2014-06-25 20:22:57">

event.sensors
  Sensor Load (12.7ms)  SELECT "sensor".* FROM "sensor" WHERE "sensor"."sid" = 4
=> [#<Sensor sid: 4, hostname: "VS-101-Z1:dna2:dna3", interface: "dna2:dna3", filter: nil, detail: 1, encoding: 0, last_cid: 50>]
```

This is where it all goes to crap, I'm expecting `VS-101-Z1:dna2:dna3` but instead I get `method_missing`:

```
event.sensors.hostname
  Sensor Load (22.4ms)  SELECT "sensor".* FROM "sensor" WHERE "sensor"."sid" = 4
NoMethodError: undefined method `hostname' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fedd377c900>
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
```

Event Table:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | signature | timestamp
  #----------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'event'
  has_many :sensors, :foreign_key => :sid
  has_many :signatures, :foreign_key => :signature
end
```

Sensor Table:

```
class Sensor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | hostname | interface
  #---------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :hostname, :interface
  self.table_name = 'sensor'
  belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => :sid
end
```

Comment: Try `event.sensors.first.hostname`

Comment: You should write `event.sensors.map(&:hostname)`. Reason `event.sensors` gives you an `Array` of *ARs* (Sensors).

Comment: Not sure who get's the gold... This returned the name. `event.sensors(&:hostname).first.hostname`

Comment: @insecure-IT -- I had a typo.. :-)If you want all the hostnames, then `#map`, or only first, then go with *Pavan*.

Comment: @ArupRakshit post it..

Comment: Better yet... `event.sensors.pluck(:hostname)`

Comment: `pluck` works on `Array` ? I was not aware of..

Comment: `pluck` works on an ActiveRecord collection, which is what `event.sensors` is returning... correct?

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra I couldn't remember it.. If you are sure.. I have np. :-)

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra Yes.. you are correct. Checked http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck :-) You can take the *Gold* then, that OP is offering..

Comment: :-) Thanks Arup...  Gold is acceptable.  I guess I'll write it up as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call an instance method on an array of objects, which is what you get when you call `event.sensors`.

If you expect a single return value, you'll have to select an instance of your array to call the instance method on, e.g. `event.sensors.first.hostname`

However, if you are looking to return an array of all the hostnames for `event.sensors` you'll probably want to use the `pluck` method described here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

```
event.sensors.pluck(:hostname)
```

This is preferable to using `map` to iterate over the array since `pluck` uses a SQL query while `map` pulls back the entire collection of ActiveRecord objects into an array and then iterates over each instance.